# Do 100% duty cycle buck converters have no voltage drop?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck, duty-cycle

I am currently designing a circuit which should be able to take 12-28V DC power in and output 12V DC @ 1.5A.

The question is: is this possible with a 100% duty cycle buck converter (like [TPS54302](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS54302))? What will happen if the input and output voltage are nearly the same?

If this is not possible what options do I have?
If it would be ok to drop up to 1V when the input voltage is below 13V, will this make things easier?

Would it be possible to detect a low voltage and bypass the converter if the voltage is too low?

Comment: "No" voltage drop would require a device to be constructed exclusively from superconducting materials, because it implies a resistance of zero. I don't think I have yet seen the announcement from the Nobel Prize Committee about that, so I suspect that with most devices, a small amount of resistance is still the best we can get. Thus any practical device will be likely to have a small voltage drop. Note that duty cycle is unrelated to voltage drop; an electrical space heater can be designed for a 100% duty cycle but drop quite a few volts.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I briefly thought about putting an "almost" in the question, but thought it is self-evident that no circuit has no voltage drop. Is the voltage drop really totally independent of duty cycle? Won't the converter have a hard time maintaining a high output voltage under load if is not capable of turning the switch on at least most of the time? Or is it just a matter of how much current is drawn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember a typical buck converter configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd9IcP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The product page indicates that duty-cycle can be %100.

If duty-cycle is %100 then the MOSFET (M1) will not act as a switch (because it's fully on). Instead, it will turn into a resistor with a value of \$R_{ds-on}\$.

So a small voltage of \$V_{DS} = R_{ds-on} \cdot I_{LOAD}\$ will drop across this resistor. For example, according to the datasheet, on-resistance is 85mR. And for a load current of 3A, the voltage drop will be about 270mV. Note that there will also be a small voltage drop across the inductor due to its DC resistance.

> Would it be possible to detect a low voltage and bypass the converter if the voltage is too low?

This is called Brown-Out Detection and a lot of chips on the market have this feature. But instead of bypassing, they tend to turn themselves off to protect the converter from drawing excessive currents.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I am unsure if the regulation will be stable, because the design tool Texas Instruments  provides for there components do not allow input and output voltages to be the same and recommend bigger and bigger components the closer the values are together. This may be because - as you said - there will always be a voltage drop and this *may* cause the regulation to become unstable. This is what I don't know.

Comment: I don't know much about the buck controller internals and therefore don't know what it will do if the output is consistently lower than the set voltage. Will it just permanently enable the transistor?

Comment: If I were you, I would use the EN function of the controller instead of worrying about duty-cycle. For example, build a comparator that pulls the EN pin low when VIN is lower than or equal to, say, 12V. Also put a relay between VIN and SW pin so that you can also bypass the the controller and direct the input to the output by shorting these pins as long as the EN pin is held low.

Answer (score 4):

Reading your question it sounds to me that a "buck-boost" converter might be more suitable for your needs. These converters can produce a fixed output voltage with inputs that range from significantly below to significantly above the output voltage. Check out offerings from Linear Technology and Texas Instruments.

This method is a lot simpler than trying to bypass the buck circuit to ensure adequate operation around 12 volts.

Comment: I thought about that, too. The problem is that these controllers incl. BOM seem to be much more complex and expensive than simple buck converters.

Comment: What price for performance and functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the linked [TPS54302 datasheet, section 7.3.10](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54302.pdf):

> To improve drop out, the TPS54302 device is designed to operate at 100% duty cycle as long as the BOOT to SW pin voltage is greater than 2.1 V (typical).

This is explained further in the TI AppNote: [Understanding 100% mode in low-power DC/DC converters](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt747/slyt747.pdf)

The answer comes down to the choice of an N-channel MOSFET for the high-side switch, requiring a gate voltage higher than the source (i.e. switched output) voltage in order to turn on the high-side MOSFET. This gate voltage is generated using the external bootstrap capacitor as a charge pump, which will gradually decay, and must be recharged to keep the high-side MOSFET turned on.

The TPS62xxx can switch the bootstrap cap independently of the output, and achieve true 100% mode operation without any off time, whereby the output voltage only depends on the high-side MOSFET's static R_DS_ON.

The TPS54xxx has the bootstrap capacitor connected to the SW output and can only recharge when the low-side mosfet is turned on, and thus the bootstrap circuit / gate voltage UVLO imposes an effective minimum off time. Figure 4 shows what seems to be ~500mV of output ripple at ~2.5kHz with a 2A load @ 5V -> 5V for the TPS54623, but it's unclear exactly how this is being measured (inductor, output capacitor value etc). Figure 5 shows a line regulation for the TPS54623 of 5V -> 5V with no load, with a slight drop from 5V -> ~4.9V at 2A load.

The [Methods to Improve Low Dropout Operation With the
TPS54240 and TPS54260](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva547a/slva547a.pdf) document has more detailed measurements, showing that this can be particularly problematic with very light loads in DCM operation, with up to 2.1V (!) of ripple. However, these are non-synchronous buck regulators with a low-side diode, and this may not apply to synchronous regulators like the TPS54623 or TPS54302 with low-side MOSFETs:

> Additionally, the newer, higher-current family of non-synchronous regulators, integrate a FET for recharging the BOOT capacitor to improve low dropout operation

Answer (score 0):

Buck Boost or SEPIC is the classical approach in case of input voltage going above and below the output one. There is another ugly way - the tapped inductor buck. It is commonly used with very high input voltages as to allow at least some duty cycle. The inductor is tapped and the fly-wheeling diode is in the tap. The inductor acts as stepping down auto transformer.
Your case is opposite. You need stepping up. The sw node from the Buck goes into the tap and the fly-wheeling diode to the left end. Another ugly option is to make the Buck fly-back i.e. put a transformer as inductor and make the secondary with slightly higher number of turns. You will even gain isolation...